# Javascript - Getting the first character of my string - error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

can you tell me why the console says that it is not a function?

```
  var firstAuthorName = document.getElementById("firstAuthorName");

var firstCharacter =  console.log(firstAuthorName.slice(0,1));
```

then I get the text by this:

```
div.innerHTML += firstCharacter.value + ", " + firstAuthorInitials.value + ", " + firstAuthorSurname.value + ". ";
```

So the console says: "Uncaught TypeError: firstAuthorName.slice is not a function"

Comment: `firstAuthorName` is an HTMLElement, not a string. Depending on what it is, you still need to consult the correct property to access its string content (like `e.value` or `e.textContent`, etc.)

Comment: You forgot a `.value`, `.innerHTML` or `.innerText` before `.slice`. `document.getElementById("firstAuthorName")` isn’t a string.

Comment: hmm, I got the input for Author's name and I need to take only the first character of his name

Answer (score 1):

**You need to access the contents of the HTML element and get the first character of that. You are attempting to get the first letter from the HTML DOM object itself, not the content of the object.**

> There are 3 standard ways to extract content of an element and which
>   you use depends on the kind of element you have and the kind of
>   content it contains:

1a. **[`value`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement)** : If the element is a form-field (radio button, checkbox,
    text box, etc.) `value` is always used to get the value being held
    in form-field.

1b. `value` is also used to obtain the value of an HTML element's attribute as in:

```js
var src = document.querySelector("img").attributes[0].value;
console.log("The value of the \"src\" attribute of the image is: " + src);
```

```html
<img src="images/someImage.jpg">
```

For non-form field elements, you can use `textContent` or `innerHTML`.

1. **[`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent)** just gets the characters that are the contents of an element (minus any HTML). If the element only contains
   human consumable text, this is most-likely what you'll want.
2. **[`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)** gets the content of the element, including any HTML CONTENT. Use this when the element in question contains HTML content
   that you want as HTML, rather than text. While using `innerHTML`
   instead of `textContent` works, it is a slightly more expensive
   operation to perform because you are asking the HTML parser to parse
   the contents, so don't use `innerHTML` on non-HTML content.

Here's a sample of all 3 of the above used correctly:

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){

  document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function(){

    var input = document.getElementById("txtTest");
    var parent = document.getElementById("parent");

    // textContent will get the text characters as they are:
    var textOnly =  console.log("textContent of parent div is: " + parent.textContent);

    // innerHTML will get the content of the element but will parse its HTML:
    var htmlContent =  console.log("innerHTML of parent div is: " + parent.innerHTML);

    // value is ONLY for form-field elements:
    console.log("The value of the div is: " + parent.value);  // undefined
    console.log("The value of the textbox is: " + input.value);

  });

});
```

```html
<input id="txtTest" type="text" placeholder="type in me and then click the button">
<div id="parent">
  <p>Nested child HTML</p>
</div>

<button>Click me to get results</button>
```

So, if your scenario is that the content is in, say a textbox, your solution would be to use `value`, like this:

```js
var firstAuthorName = document.getElementById("firstAuthorName");
var button = document.querySelector("button");

button.addEventListener("click", function(){
  console.log("The first character in the textbox is: " + firstAuthorName.value.slice(0,1));
});
```

```html
<input id="firstAuthorName" type="text" placeholder="type in me and then click the button">
<button>Click Me</button>
```